# Перетаскивание блоков в ячейки с последующей проверкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть страница, нужно перенести блоки "три" и "четыре" в левую ячейку, а "шесть" и "семь" в правую. После нажатия кнопки, проверить, правильно или нет. Спасибо.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
  .container{overflow:hidden;width:100%}
  .box{white-space:nowrap}
  .box div{width:90px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black}
  td {border: 1px solid;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="box">
       <div>один</div>
       <div>два</div>
       <div>три</div>
       <div>четыре</div>
       <div>пять</div>
       <div>шесть</div>
       <div>семь</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>
         вот сюда надо перенести 3 и 4
       </td>
       <td>
        вот сюда надо перенести 6 и 7
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" name="button">Проверить</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/drag-and-drop

Comment: дубликат + учебное задание https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866912/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-div-%D0%BF%D0%BE-id-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понял поставленную задачу:

```js
function fAllowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
}
function fDrag(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
  event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.id);
}
function fDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  var oClone = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
  //var oClone = document.getElementById(data);
  if (event.currentTarget.children.length < 2) {
    oClone.draggable = false;
    oClone.removeAttribute('id');
    oClone.removeEventListener('dragstart', fDrag);
    event.currentTarget.appendChild(oClone);
  }
}

function fCheck() {
  if (oFieldCompare_1.children.length == 2 && oFieldCompare_2.children.length == 2) {
    let rExp_1 = /тричетыре|четыретри/;
    let rExp_2 = /шестьсемь|семьшесть/;
    if (rExp_1.test(oFieldCompare_1.textContent) && rExp_2.test(oFieldCompare_2.textContent)) {
      оButtonCheck.outerHTML = 'УРА! ВСЁ СОШЛОСЬ!';
    }
  }
}

function fRainbowElem(oElem) {
  let aChild = oElem.children;
  let nStepHue = 360 / aChild.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < aChild.length; i++) {
    aChild[i].draggable = true;
    aChild[i].id = 'id_' + i;
    aChild[i].setAttribute('user-key', i);
    aChild[i].addEventListener('dragstart', fDrag);
    aChild[i].style.backgroundColor = 'hsla(' + (nStepHue * i) + ', 100%, 50%, .5)';
  }
}

var оTableCompare = document.querySelector('table');
var oFieldCompare_1 = оTableCompare.rows[0].cells[0];
oFieldCompare_1.addEventListener('drop', fDrop);
oFieldCompare_1.addEventListener('dragover', fAllowDrop);
var oFieldCompare_2 = оTableCompare.rows[0].cells[1];
oFieldCompare_2.addEventListener('drop', fDrop);
oFieldCompare_2.addEventListener('dragover', fAllowDrop);

var оButtonCheck = document.querySelector('button');
оButtonCheck.addEventListener('click', fCheck);

fRainbowElem(document.querySelector('div.box'))
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box div {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 185px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>один</div>
    <div>два</div>
    <div>три</div>
    <div>четыре</div>
    <div>пять</div>
    <div>шесть</div>
    <div>семь</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button type="button" name="button">Проверить</button>
```

Если что-то будет непонятно, то дополню код комментариями позже.

Comment: Если неправильно, как об этом сообщить? Например рядом с кнопкой: неправильно. Спасибо!