# Проверка дочернего элемента div по id элемента

Tags: javascript, html

Есть div'ы, которые перетаскиваются вниз к блокам. Как мне проверить что div'ы попали на правильный блок.
Например: div: aaa,bbb должны попасть в блок 1, а ccc в блок 2
Желательно чтобы после проверки выскакивало правильно/неправильно

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    </script>
    <style>
        .draggable {
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: inline;
            height: 20px;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
        #target {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        #target2 {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="draggable1" class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">aaa</div>
    <div id="draggable2" class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">bbb</div>
    <div id="draggable3" class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">ccc</div>
    <div id="draggable4" class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">ddd</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    1
    <div id="target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    2
    <div id="target2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <button>Проверить</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: дубликат + учебное задание https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866820/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: Правильно.. Зачем напрягаться и делать сайт самостоятельно, когда можно зайти на этот форум, задать пару вопросов и собрать готовую механику.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так)
Для блоков в которые перетаскиваешь элементы добавь атрибут с индивидуальным значением data-owner="1"
Для блоков которые перетаскиваешь добавляешь атрибут data-parent со значение которое ты указал для родительских блоках, так же для них обязателен класс draggable

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}


$('body').ready(function(){

    $( "#test" ).click(function() {
        var count = $('.draggable').length;
        $('#rez').html('');
        for(var i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            var drag = $('#draggable'+i).data('parent');
            var parent = $('#draggable'+i).parent();
            var owner = parent.data('owner');
            var name = $('#draggable'+i).html();
            if(drag == owner)
            {
                $('#rez').append('Блок '+name+' на своем месте<br>');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#rez').append('Блок '+name+' НЕ на своем месте<br>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.draggable {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#target {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
}
#target2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable0" data-parent="1" class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">aaa</div>
<div id="draggable1" data-parent="1" class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">bbb</div>
<div id="draggable2" data-parent="2" class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">ccc</div>
<div id="draggable3" data-parent="2" class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">ddd</div>
<br>
<br>
1
<div id="target" data-owner="1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
2
<div id="target2" data-owner="2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<button id="test">Проверить</button>
<div id="rez"></div>
```