# Перетаскивание изображений по блокам с проверкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
div#trg1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
div#trg2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
button#resultbutton {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgblock">
<img id="img1" src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/1.png">
<img id="img2" src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/2.png">
<img id="img3" src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/3.png">
<img id="img4" src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/4.png">
</div>
<p>Блок 1</p>
<div id="trg1" class="target1">
</div>
<p>Блок 2</p>
<div id="trg2" class="target2">
</div>
<button id="resultbutton" class="resultbutton" name="button">Проверить</button>
```

Есть форма, как можно перетаскивать изображения в `div'ы.` И после нажатия на кнопку проверить, в правильных блоках находятся ли. Например: цифры 1 и 3 в блок 1, а 2 и 4 в блок 2. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот, первая ссылка в гугле http://gearmobile.github.io/javascript/javascript-drag-and-drop/. Все довольно подробно описано. С чем возникли проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Задачи нужно решать самому. Тогда будет понимание алгоритмов и механики. Недавно уже отвечал на точь-в-точь такой же вопрос (учебник то один на всех))) - [Перетаскивание блоков в ячейки с последующей проверкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866911/265406)